# how to group by data from hive with specific partition?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

I have the following:

```
hive>show partitions TABLENAME                                                           
pt=2012.07.28.08                                                                         
pt=2012.07.28.09                                                                         
pt=2012.07.28.10                                                                         
pt=2012.07.28.11                                                                         
hive> select pt,count(*) from TABLENAME group by pt;                                     
OK
```

Why can't the `group by` get the data?

Comment: what is the result of `select count(*) from TABLENAME`? are you sure you have data in the partitions?

Comment: I suppose there is data, otherwise partitions cant be created, am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `hive.mapred.mode` is set to `"strict"`, if so it'll not allow all partitions to scan for the submitted query. You can set it to nonstrict as below:

```
hive>set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
```

I'm not sure whether this caused NO results out of your query, but trying to address it. Do share the results.

**Note:** You can check the default value for this parameter in `hive-default.xml`

Comment: Thank you.I set hive.mapred.mode =strict and then fire query (select pt,count(*) from Table group by pt) but i got error like AILED: SemanticException org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Answer (score 1):

You can always achive the same using 2 select statements . For ex

```
Create table table1(
session_id string,
page_id string
)
partitioned by (metrics_date string);
```

Consider we are have loaded table for 2 partitions

> hive>show partitions table1
>   metrics_date=2012.07.28.08
>   metrics_date=2012.07.28.09

```
select * from table1 ;

1212121212    google.com     2012.07.28.08 

1212121212    google.com     2012.07.28.09`
```

**Getting number of rows per partition**

```
select metrics_date,count(*) from (
select * from table1 ) temp
group by metrics_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get whole results along with group by ,You can use the below query.

```
SELECT pt,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pt) FROM TABLENAME;
```

This can be achiened through partition by.

Comment: Getting `HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.`